# Is a type 1 error a true positive?

Tags: type-i-and-ii-errors

Type one error is if $H_0 $ is true, but the test is showing that $H_1$ is true.

Is type 1 error a true negative then and type 2 error a false positive?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to CV.SE! I think you might want to check the text in the main question  (which you ask for TP) and body (which you ask for TN). Nonetheless, the convention I am aware of designates $H_1$ as the "positive class", and hence type one error is usually referred as a false positive.

Comment: What is TP and TN?

Comment: TP = True Positive, TN = True Negative in my comment above

Comment: Any thought of equating "error" with "true" is strange...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type I errors are incorrect rejections of a true null hypothesis. I would call this a false positive, though the alternative might be a negative event (disease, accident, etc).

Type II errors are when you fail to catch that the null hypothesis is false. I would call this a false negative, even though we don’t quite accept a null hypothesis.

Comment: As an additon, an explanation why $H_0$ is considered "negative": In hypothesis testing, the *Null Hypothesis* $H_0$ is usually the opposite from what you want to show. $H_0$ is thus something that you know or hope to be false and you are looking for statistical evidence (aka "p value") that that it is unlikely to be true. Rejecting $H_0$ is thus finding a "positive".